# Passing callback/promise to action creator from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react component from where I want to set some state in redux and when state is set I want to do some other stuff in the component.

```
 // Inside Component
 onButtnClick() {
       const currentTime = moment.tz('US/Eastern').valueOf();
       this.props.updateDataInReduxState(currentTime, () => {
                // this should not be called until current time is set.
                this.props.openInputModalToShowTime();
       });
 }

 // Inside actions
 function updateDataInReduxState(currentTime, callback) {
     // how can I call callback after state updates successfully, 
     // to ensure correct time is shown in the modal?
     return {
        type: UPDATE_TIME,
        payload: currentTime
     }
 )

 function openInputModalToShowTime() {
   return {
        type: SHOW_MODAL,
        payload: true
     }
 }

 // Modal Component listens on redux state state.showmodal, if true it opens 
 // and displays time stored in redux state state.currentTime
```

Comment: I don't have to re render, I just want to do some more stuff after setting a state in redux. Hence that some more stuff I am doing inside callback, which I expect actioncreator to call after dispatching action.

Comment: Er, I'm sure there's a better way to go about this, but you could set a redux state to a boolean and pass that down and have a ternary for when it's true. You set that boolean to true after an update and then dispatch an action to set it to false after completing the additional action in your component. As I said, there's most likely a more elegant solution, but I just thought of that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be dispatching an action inside another action creator(function *updateDataInReduxState* in your case). Action creators are simply used to dispatch an action, which in turn is listened by a reducer and state is changed accordingly.

You can handle your case like this.

```
//Inside component, dispatch updateData action without any callback
onButtnClick() {
    const currentTime = moment.tz('US/Eastern').valueOf();
    this.props.updateDataInReduxState(currentTime);
}

//Now listen to your prop updates and once current time prop is set in your state, dispatch your openInputModalToShowTime action
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.hasOwnProperty('currentTime') && nextProps.currentTime != null){
      this.props.openInputModalToShowTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: This comes as a side effect of extra re-render, because now my component will listen to currentTime state?

Comment: Obviously it should listen to your currentTime prop in state. That's what state is meant for. By listening to the callback after updating your state, you are essentially doing the same thing which state does automatically for you.

Comment: Listening to a callback wont call render again, correct? Your answer is awesome I am just thinking whether I can avoid calling of render again

Comment: Don't worry. React manages all this in a virtual DOM so it won't re-render until something changes in your DOM. And in your case, you want to call the callback when currentTime gets updated in your state. Since the state changes in this case also, so it would listen to change in state in this case as well.

Comment: But I wouldn't have included currentTime in mapstateToProps, but you are true react will take care of it

Comment: But in your question you wrote that your modal will show the current time from your state(state.currentTime). And even if you don't keep that prop in state, implementing callback would probably be an overkill for such simple changes. React can handles tons of manipulations easily.

And anyways using action creators for anything other than dispatching action is not how you should be using Redux.

Comment: Yes thats correct but component to show current time is a different component which will listen to currenttime. Anyhow whatever you mentioned makes sense, callback is an overkill

Comment: Indeed. Redux is meant for that sort of handling. Don't worry, keeping current time in state won't impact anything. In case you need to continue the discussion or need any other help, you can join me on slack here - https://code-slayers-den.slack.com/ . I have created this group for fellow devs.

Comment: please invite me on slack, agrawall.lokesh@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but it seems you just wanna show a modal after the redux state is updated. Since dispatching an action is synchronous, you don't need a callback to do the job. I think you can have a local state(not redux state) in your component called `showModal` which is initialized to `false`. Then, in the `onButtonClick()` function, you dispatch an action to update the redux state, and then call `setState` to set the local state `showModal` to `true`. And in your render function of the component, you have something like `{this.state.showModal && <ModalComponent />}`. The name `ModalComponent`is just an example, it might be a simple `<div>xxxx</div>` instead. Make sure you reset the state to false when you close the modal.

Comment: What if that actioncreator makes a server call and then dispatches an action. I feel its always better to either pass a callback or return promise if you want to make sure that dispatch is done.

Comment: I don't see any server call in your description, but you're right, if there is a server call, a promise is a good practice. I personally only use promise when it's necessary.